# Break up each dataframe row text into five even chunks of text

Tags: r, dataframe

I was hoping for some assistance with this thorny string problem.

Current dataframe

```
ID  Text
1   This is a very long piece of string. This contains many lines.
```

I would like to transform it to:

```
ID   Text1            Text2            Text3           Text4         Text5
1    This is a        very long piece  of string.      This contains  many lines.
```

The string split should occur on evenly spliced amount of words. In the example above I have attempted to demonstrate the line split evenly 5 times, so each column should contain 20% of the words.

The objective behind this is to frame these words into such a manner that they can be looked at as time series data as a conversation has just been split up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably a better option to do it but this works with no additional package:

First thing, we create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example):

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:2,
                 Text=c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then, `chunkize` is a wrapper around `split`+`cut` that is the tricky part. It takes a `character`, split it on spaces and into `n` chunks, then returns a `data.frame` with `n` many columns. (We remove `names` so that the `rbind` downwards is fine).

```
chunkize <- function(chr, n=5){
  x <- strsplit(chr, " ")[[1]]
  df <- as.data.frame(
    lapply(
      split(x, 
            cut(seq_along(x), 
                breaks=n)), 
      paste, collapse=" "), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names=NULL)
  names(df) <- NULL
  df
}
```

Then we simply apply it for every row. We also add the the `ID` column:

```
df_chunked <- do.call("rbind", 
                      apply(df, 1, 
                         function(x) cbind(x[1], chunkize(x[-1], 5))))
```

Finally, we rename columns:

```
colnames(df_chunked) <- c("ID", paste0("Text", 1:5))
```

---

Same thing into an handy function:

```
chunkize_this <- function(df, n=5){
  chunkize <- function(chr, n){
    x <- strsplit(chr, " ")[[1]]
    df <- as.data.frame(
      lapply(
        split(x, 
              cut(seq_along(x), 
                  breaks=n)), 
        paste, collapse=" "), 
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names=NULL)
    names(df) <- NULL
    df
  }

  df_chunked <- do.call("rbind", 
                        apply(df, 1, function(x) cbind(x[1], chunkize(x[-1], n))))
  colnames(df_chunked) <- c(colnames(df)[1], paste0("Text", 1:n))
  rownames(df_chunked) <- NULL
  df_chunked
}
```

You can try it with:

```
View(chunkize_this(df, 3))
View(chunkize_this(df, 5))
```

Another example:

```
df <- read.table(h=T, text=
  'ID   Text
  1    "This is a very long piece of string. This contains many lines."
  2    "This is a very long piece of string. It contains one or two more word."
  3    "Short"'
)

> chunkize_this(df, 5)
ID     Text1           Text2         Text3           Text4                Text5
1  1 This is a       very long      piece of    string. This contains many lines.
2  2 This is a very long piece of string. It contains one or       two more word.
3  3                                   Short
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you. This worked amazingly well. Rows are splitting up equally as I was hoping.  For further context, I have been attempting to apply Topic #5 in this paper where this type of action is required. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.04462.pdf

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approaches with implementations in `data.table`, base R and the `tidyverse`. The number of parts can be hard-coded or pre-allocated:

```
# pre-allocating number of parts
np <- 5
```

The different alternatives:

**1) with 'data.table':**

```
library(data.table)

# method 1
setDT(DF)[, strsplit(Text, "\\s"), by = ID
          ][, grp := rleid(cut(1:.N, np)), by = ID
            ][, paste(V1, collapse = " "), by = .(ID, grp)
              ][, dcast(.SD, ID ~ paste0('Text', grp), value.var = "V1")]

# method 2
setDT(DF)[, strsplit(Text, ' '), by = ID
          ][, grp := {s <- ceiling(.N/np); rleid(s:(.N+s-1) %/% (.N/np))}, by = ID
            ][, paste(V1, collapse = ' '), by = .(ID, grp)
              ][, dcast(.SD, ID ~ paste0('Text', grp), value.var = 'V1')]
```

which both give:

> ```
>    ID     Text1           Text2         Text3           Text4                Text5
> 1:  1   This is     a very long      piece of    string. This contains many lines.
> 2:  2 This is a very long piece of string. It contains one or      two more words.
> 3:  3     Short            text            NA              NA                   NA
> ```

**2) base R:**

```
# method 1
equal_parts <- function(x, np = 5) {
  n <- cut(seq_along(x), np)
  n <- as.integer(n)
  cumsum(c(1, diff(n) > 0))
}

# method 2
equal_parts <- function(x, np = 5) {
  n <- length(x)
  s <- ceiling(n/np)
  rl <- rle(s:(n+s-1) %/% (n/np))$lengths
  rep(seq_along(rl), rl)
}

DF.long <- stack(setNames(strsplit(DF$Text, ' '), DF$ID))

DF.long$grp <- with(DF.long, ave(values, ind, FUN =  equal_parts))
DF.agg <- aggregate(values ~ ind + grp, DF.long, paste0, collapse = ' ')

reshape(DF.agg, idvar = 'ind', timevar = 'grp', direction = 'wide')
```

which gives:

> ```
>   ind  values.1        values.2      values.3        values.4             values.5
> 1   1   This is     a very long      piece of    string. This contains many lines.
> 2   2 This is a very long piece of string. It contains one or      two more words.
> 3   3     Short            text          <NA>            <NA>                 <NA>
> ```

**3) 'tidyverse':**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(DF, Text) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(grp = equal_parts(Text)) %>%     # using the 'equal_parts'-function from the base R solution
  group_by(grp, add = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(Text = paste0(Text, collapse = ' ')) %>% 
  spread(grp, Text)
```

which gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 6
> # Groups:   ID [3]
>      ID       `1`             `2`           `3`             `4`                  `5`
> * <int>     <chr>           <chr>         <chr>           <chr>                <chr>
> 1     1   This is     a very long      piece of    string. This contains many lines.
> 2     2 This is a very long piece of string. It contains one or      two more words.
> 3     3     Short            text          <NA>            <NA>                 <NA>
> ```

---

Used data:

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Text = c("This is a very long piece of string. This contains many lines.", 
                                        "This is a very long piece of string. It contains one or two more words.", 
                                        "Short text")),
                .Names = c("ID", "Text"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This doesn't give the correct outcome imo, as the number of words per column varies by row ;-)

Comment: @Uwe It does. OP wants to split the text in 5 parts (which also becomes clear when looking at the desired output).

Comment: Perhaps, you are right but the sample data with just one row gives room for interpretation / speculation. BTW, my gut feeling that it might be an X-Y problem.

Comment: Many thanks for this solution. I am most comfortable using tidyverse, so have used that to implement the solution. It has worked exactly as I have hoped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The OP has supplied a data frame with only one row. Therefore, it is unclear what the expected result is in case of multiple rows with varying number of words in `text`. Is it required that

1. the resulting columns contain the same number of words (if sufficient words are available), or,
2. each row is split up separately?

### Solution for case 1

If the requirement is that each column should contain the same number of words across all rows (if sufficient words are available), the row with the most words determines the distribution. Columns of rows with less words are filled up from the left (*left aligned*).

```
library(data.table)
n_brks <- 5L
setDT(DT)[, strsplit(Text, "\\s"), by = ID][
  , paste(V1, collapse = " "), by = .(ID, cut(rowid(ID), n_brks))][
    , dcast(.SD, ID ~ rowid(ID, prefix = "Text"), fill = "", value.var = "V1")]
```

> ```
>    ID      Text1           Text2           Text3                Text4           Text5
> 1:  1  This is a very long piece of string. This contains many lines.                
> 2:  2  This is a very long piece   of string. It      contains one or two more words.
> 3:  3 Short text                                                                     
> 4:  4    Shorter
> ```

Columns `Text1` to `Text4` contain the *same number of words* (3 each) for rows 1 and 2. The rows with less words than columns are fill up from the left.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
```

> ```
> DT <- fread(
>   'ID   Text
>    1    "This is a very long piece of string. This contains many lines."
>    2    "This is a very long piece of string. It contains one or two more words."
>    3    "Short text"
>    4     "Shorter"')
> ```

#### Explanation

After coersion to data.table, the text in each row is split up at word boundaries and returned in long format (which might be seen as equivalent to a time series):

```
n_brks <- 5L
setDT(DT)[, strsplit(Text, "\\s"), by = ID]
```

> ```
>     ID       V1
>  1:  1     This
>  2:  1       is
>  3:  1        a
>  4:  1     very
>  5:  1     long
>  6:  1    piece
>  7:  1       of
>  8:  1  string.
>  9:  1     This
> 10:  1 contains
> 11:  1     many
> 12:  1   lines.
> 13:  2     This
> 14:  2       is
> 15:  2        a
> 16:  2     very
> 17:  2     long
> 18:  2    piece
> 19:  2       of
> 20:  2  string.
> 21:  2       It
> 22:  2 contains
> 23:  2      one
> 24:  2       or
> 25:  2      two
> 26:  2     more
> 27:  2   words.
> 28:  3    Short
> 29:  3     text
> 30:  4  Shorter
>     ID       V1
> ```

Then the words are concatenated again using a computed grouping variable which uses the `cut()` function on the `rowdid()` numbering to create `n_brks` chunks:

```
setDT(DT)[, strsplit(Text, "\\s"), by = ID][
  , paste(V1, collapse = " "), by = .(ID, cut(rowid(ID), n_brks))]
```

> ```
>     ID         cut                   V1
>  1:  1 (0.986,3.8]            This is a
>  2:  1   (3.8,6.6]      very long piece
>  3:  1   (6.6,9.4]      of string. This
>  4:  1  (9.4,12.2] contains many lines.
>  5:  2 (0.986,3.8]            This is a
>  6:  2   (3.8,6.6]      very long piece
>  7:  2   (6.6,9.4]        of string. It
>  8:  2  (9.4,12.2]      contains one or
>  9:  2   (12.2,15]      two more words.
> 10:  3 (0.986,3.8]           Short text
> 11:  4 (0.986,3.8]              Shorter
> ```

Finally, this result is reshaped again from long into wide format to create the expected result. The column headers are created by the `rowid()` function and missing values are replaced by `""`:

```
setDT(DT)[, strsplit(Text, "\\s"), by = ID][
  , paste(V1, collapse = " "), by = .(ID, cut(rowid(ID), n_brks))][
    , dcast(.SD, ID ~ rowid(ID, prefix = "Text"), fill = "", value.var = "V1")]
```

### Solution for case 2

If the requirement is that each row individually should be split up and the words distributed evenly, the number of words in each column will vary from column to column. Rows with less words than columns will have one word per column at most.

The solution for this case is a modification of [Jaaps's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502534/break-up-each-dataframe-row-text-into-five-even-chunks-of-text/46502975#comment79968416_46502975):

```
library(data.table)
n_brks <- 5L
setDT(DT)[, strsplit(Text, "\\s"), by = ID][
  , ri := cut(seq_len(.N), n_brks), by = ID][
    , paste(V1, collapse = " "), by = .(ID, ri)][
      , dcast(.SD, ID ~ rowid(ID, prefix = "Text"), fill = "", value.var = "V1")]
```

> ```
>    ID     Text1           Text2         Text3           Text4                Text5
> 1:  1 This is a       very long      piece of    string. This contains many lines.
> 2:  2 This is a very long piece of string. It contains one or      two more words.
> 3:  3     Short            text                                                   
> 4:  4   Shorter
> ```

Now, the number of words in each column is varying by row. E.g., columns `Text2` to `Text4` have 2 words each in row 1 and 3 words each in row 2. The 2 words of row 3 are placed in separate columns.

Comment: This doesn't give the correct outcome imo, see the first row which doesn't have five text groups.

Comment: A possible alternative: `setDT(DT)[, strsplit(Text, "\\s"), by = ID][, ri := rowid(ID)][, ri := cut(ri, 5), by = ID][, paste(V1, collapse = " "), by = .(ID, ri)][, dcast(.SD, ID ~ rowid(ID, prefix = "Text"), fill = "", value.var = "V1")]`

Comment: Apologies about any confusion caused. It was case 1 for the question I had. Also your solution works wonderfully. Thank you.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback and confirmation that you were seeking a solution for case 1. But, why did you accept a solution for case 2, then? (Please, don't get me wrong. I'm just curious)

Comment: Oh wait. I realise what you mean. Case 2 is what I am looking for. I needed to re-read that part carefully.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.